# MultiPreviewDevices feature in Android Studio (Electric Eel)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

I have created below details in separate file

```
@Preview(showBackground = true,
uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO or Configuration.UI_MODE_TYPE_NORMAL,
device = "spec:shape=Normal, width=673, height=841, unit=dp,dpi=480", name = "Phone",)

annotation class PreviewDevices(){}
```

I am getting below error.

```
**This annotation is not applicable to target 'annotation class'**
```

I am using latest Android Studio (Electric Eel) Canary version.

Comment: Looks like i need to use compose version: "1.2.0-beta01".....its working now

Comment: You can either remove the question, or provide an answer explicitly to let people know the query has been resolved, sir.